# How to get the index of an option in a select menu by matching the text with plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, indexing, select-menu

I have a select menu and I need to dynamically select the option based on the text value of the option element. For example, my select looks like this:

```
<select id="names">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Steve</option>
    <option value="3">Max</option>
</select>
```

If I have the string "Max", how can I get that the index of the option is 4 so I can dynamically set this as the selectedIndex with JavaScript?

No jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/x8f7g/1/

You want to select the element, iterate over the array, find the text value, and return the index.

- Don't use InnerHTML, it's slow and breaks and not standards compliant
- Dont use innerText, simmilar reasons but not quite as serious
- Do use a function so you can do it all over again.
- Do select the child text node, and retreives the nodeValue, which is cross-browser friendly

---

Example:

```
function indexMatchingText(ele, text) {
    for (var i=0; i<ele.length;i++) {
        if (ele[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue === text){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it should find and then select the relevant option in the select box.

```
var searchtext = "max";
for (var i = 0; i < listbox.options.length; ++i) {
    if (listbox.options[i].text === searchtext) listbox.options[i].selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this short function to do that:

```
function findIndexfromOptionName( select, optionName ) {
    let options = Array.from( select.options );
    return options.findIndex( (opt) => opt.label == optionName );
}
```

**Arguments:**

- `select`: an `HTMLSelect` *element*
- `optionName`: as a `string`

**Explanation:** 
On the first line of the function body we retrieve the `<select>` *options* as an `array` using `Array.from()`.
This allow us to use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to return the index of the first option that match the provided name, if any or return **-1** if there is no match.

Want some reasons to use it ? 
It has a short implementation and the semantic is pretty clear. Also pure JS.

Comment: You're implementation appears to be fine (elegant, you could even chain the calls to make a one-liner), but this is a **12 year old question** that already had **9 existing answers**. Does this really add anything new?

Comment: Thought its a 12 year old question it was the first one to show up on google search engine that's why I decided to post an updated answer. Edit here is the search string used: _get the index of an <option> inside a <select> from its name js_

Comment: Fair enough +1. Just an FYI though people *frequently* post plagarized (literal copy-paste of an existing answer), incorrect answers, and flat-out spam on old questions especially (no offense) users that haven't acquired a lot of rep on the site yet. It always raises a bit of a red flag when scrolling through the feed. I don't want to discourage you from doing it when it's needed but people may question it (like I did here).

Comment: @JaredSmith it's the only answer not explicitly looping over the options, and I tried it because I find it the most elegant. I strongly encourage Darkosphere to try to improve old answers

Comment: @Lante Dellarovere glad to hear the answer was helpful. After all that's why we usually post them. :p

Answer (score 3):

```
var opts = document.getElementById("names").options;
for(var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if(opts[i].innerText == "Max") {
        alert("found it at index " + i + " or number " + (i + 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFD5p/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it has to be plain JavaScript -- no jQuery!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages/Using_the_W3C_DOM#Changing_an_Element's_Text_Using_the_DOM

Answer (score 1):

The options property stores the options in a select menu - iterate over it and compare the contents.

```
var list = document.getElementById("names").options;

for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].text== "Max") { //Compare
        list[i].selected = true; //Select the option.
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuTxu/2

Comment: @Incognito Updated my answer.  Is it really so bad that "assassinates" is a valid description?

Comment: Absolutely, it's a non-standard thing that treats the DOM as if the object-model is raw-text to be altered all willy-nilly, it's not part of the spec either. Go see how bad it is performance wise for yourself on jsperf.

Comment: @Incognito Good to know.  I hadn't realized that it was not part of the standard.

Comment: It's because of how the DOM works, MISE introduced innerHTML wayyyy back, anyone who uses it surrenders their right to badmouth IE6 :P. It's because once HTML is read by your browser as *objects* in memory, not a string that's parsed as html each time a change is made to the document. Browsers force it to work because of "backwards compatibility," and it leads to more problems and a slower experience for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

in PLAIN js

```
var sel, opts, opt, x, txt;
txt='Max';
sel=document.getElementById('names');
opts=sel.options;
for (x=0;x<opts.lenght;x++){
    if (opts[x].text === txt){
        opt=opts[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[edit - expanded to include non-jquery method]**

I *strongly recommend* using jQuery for this since the solution is a one-liner:

```
jQuery('#names option:contains("Max")').val()
```

However, here's a pure JavaScript implementation anyway:

```
function findOption( select, matchMe ) {

  var

    // list of child options
    options = select.getElementsByTagName('option'),

    // iteration vars
    i = options.length,
    text,
    option;

  while (i--) {

    option = options[i];
    text = option.textContent || option.innerText || '';

    // (optional) add additional processing to text, such as trimming whitespace
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g);

    if (text === matchMe) {
      return option.getAttribute('value');
    }

  }

  return null;

}
```

Example usage:

```
alert(
  findOption(
    document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],
    "Max"
  )
);
```

Alerts `3`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it has to be plain JavaScript -- no jQuery!

Comment: I strongly recommend learning how to use plain JavaScript and becoming aware of what would make jQuery undesirable for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("names");
for(var i = 0; i<x.options.length; i++){
    if("Max" == x.options[i].text){
        doSomething();
        //maybe x.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This selects by the value, not the text node's value.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].children,
    i,
    l = options.length,
    index;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
  if(options[i].firstChild.nodeValue === 'Max'){index = i};
}
```

Please note that the index is zero based, what mean it is one less than you would expect.